# sqldatareader error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I want to check if the sqldatareader is null or not.  So tried the following code:

```
if (x[k]!= DBNull.Value)   
{
  box.Text = Convert.ToString(x[k++]);

  if ((box.Text) != "")
    current[j - 1] = Convert.ToDouble(box.Text);
  else current[j - 1] = 0;

  box.Enabled = false;
}
```

However while trying to check the value within the datareader, it throws an error,"invalid attempt to read data when no data is present". How else should i check to see if data is there or not.!! please help. here x is an sqldatareader 
SqlDataReader x = cmd.ExecuteReader();
and cmd is a select commnand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a null check and Has Row before accessing the DataRows.

like this

```
if(null != x && x.HasRows)
{
//Your code
}
```

Comment: but still its showing the same error. !! although the if condition is satisfied, it is not able to execute the line 
box.Text = Convert.ToString(x[k++]);
the fieldcount of x shows 6 but then why is it not able to read x[k] ? even when k = 0.

Comment: Try Quickwatch the value of the x[k].

Comment: is it possible to look into the value stored within the datareader? i mean, i dont think there is a way to peep into the value within x[0] or x[1]..

Comment: Yes using Quick watch feature you can do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SqlDataReader.HasRows` - it is true if at least one row of data is present, alternatively you can read through all results using `SqlDataReader.Read()`;

So for your example:

```
while(x.Read())
{
  //read stuff
}
```